# How is this representation of nth dimensional space called?

Tags: vector-spaces

I have been looking into Vector Math as of recently and had this idea of a 3D representation of more or less any dimension you want.
I can hardly imagine it is my idea however and it seems rather useless for any other use than vectors.

[image]

This is the basic idea. We just add another axis for each new dimension. And that's pretty much it. How is it called? And where is it used? From what I have been able to tell, this representation only does anything good for vectors. But any 3D or 6D object just looks confusing. And the moment you try to project some 6D cube into the 3rd dimension, it's just a plane more or less.

But again, it works pretty well for vectors.

So yeah, thanks for the help !

Comment: lt seems it is basically projection to 2d.

Comment: It looks like a 2D representation to me.

Comment: It's called an orthogonal projection. Basically I think such a projection can be characterized by an idempotent and self adjoint matrix, I'm not sure though.

Comment: Actually I should point out that if you want your projection to be orthogonal (that is not skewed in some way), you cannot add a new axis randomly. For example, once you draw the x and y axis, the z axis is predetermined. I'm not sure if this is the case for higher dimensions though...

Comment: A big problem with any dimension beyond the 4th one is the position of the axis. I havent found a real rule of where to put them. The only rule there is is that all negative ones should be on the same side. But not more than that.